# Cannot call 'Size' property of win32com.client.Dispatch AppointmentItem after getting Outlook Appointments

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, win32com, mapi

I am using **win32com.client** to access Outlook application. I successfully managed to get the appointments from the calendar but I am interested in getting the number of appointments without getting into **for** loop.

I am doing the following:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')

appointments = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items

appointments.Sort("[Start]")
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"

restriction = "[Start] >= '" + start_date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d') + "' AND [Start] <= '" + \
              end_date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d') + "'"
restricted_items = appointments.Restrict(restriction)
print(restricted_items.Size)
```

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link, describing the AppointmentItem API, I found out that I can get the Size of the Outlook object. But it throws an exception

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library._Items instance at 0x73837256>' object has no attribute 'size'
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I want to use this in order to check for any appointments retrieved as a result of above query so that I do not use the `restriction` object on `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Restrict` return [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-object-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) collection. It does not expose the Size property - what you need is `Count`.

And if the size of the collection is not know ahead of time (Outlook calculates it on demand), use `Items.GetFirst/GetNext` to loop through the items in the collection.

Comment: Sorry for commenting after a while, but `Count` isn't working as well.
I have entered the dates for which I do not have any items for `Restrict`. For that I would expect `Count` to be `0`. But it returns something like `2147483647`.

Comment: 2147483647 is -1. This means OOM does not know yet, you'd need to loop through the items using Items.GetFirst/GetNext

Comment: I solved my problem by using `if restricted_items.GetFirst()`. Please change your answer accordingly so that I accept it.